# Resources for .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Lately at work, I've been doing a lot of redirects using Apache .htaccess. Does anybody know of any good resources that thoroughly go through .htaccess and all the possibilities?Mainly working with HTML and Wordpress PHP

There are some answers on here, but I'm talking about starting from scratch and step by step.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend going through the Apache documentation - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html